# Changing value of TextView from Dialogs

Tags: android, dialog, textview

I'm trying to make change a `TextView` 's text by the value submitted from a `EditText` on a `Dialog`.

There's one `Dialog` that makes you **Add** the amount and on makes you **Remove** it from the `TextView`.

What I don't get is why when I click on '**Add**' or '**Remove**' the app **crashes**.

Here's the entire `Code` (Java and XMLs)

http://pastebin.com/er3zTe4V

-- Error --

```
09-14 20:49:55.661  31774-31774/com.hfad.pocket E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.hfad.pocket, PID: 31774
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.hfad.pocket.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:32)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:163)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Can you paste the most relevant parts into your post, please? If you add the stacktrace from the crash that would also be super.

Comment: Sure thing! @codeMagic

Comment: is your textview in the dialog or in the activity?

Comment: Activity, not in the Dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `EditText` is in the dialog layout, you need to call `findViewById` on your dialog:

```
EditText transaction = (EditText) ((AlertDialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you, but, may I ask for an explanation? Thanks again!

Comment: What's confusing you?

Comment: The reason of that Dialog in brackets

Comment: Uhm.. May I ask you how can I get back a variable just saved on the bundle? I mean, I saved it before quitting the app, and got it back on the onCreate method, but then it ends, how can I access that variable inside another method?? (The variable is currentMoney) @karaokyo

Comment: It's being typecast to a AlertDialog so that you can access the View methods

Comment: You can save whatever variable you need to a field variable that can be accessed anywhere in the class

Comment: 1st Thanks for the explanation, it helped. 2nd I found out how to use that variable myself, but thanks anyway! :)